# Convert this Mootools code into jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I'm want to convert  script to jQuery, but it dosen't work... it was Mootools code :

```
var bg = $('#counter');
var ctx = ctx = bg.getContext('2d');
var imd = null;
var circ = Math.PI * 2;
var quart = Math.PI / 2;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = '#99CC33';
ctx.lineCap = 'square';
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 10.0;

imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);

ctx.putImageData(imd, 0, 0);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(120, 120, 70, -(quart), ((circ) * 0.5) - quart, false);
ctx.stroke();
```

Here is the jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Aapn8/2832/

I tried to replace the `document.id` with the jquery selector `$('')`, nothing...

Thanks !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about converting a specific script to a different library. This won't be useful for anyone else.

Comment: It's about learning differences between two libraries by exemple, for others ;)

Comment: If you have a specific question, you can ask it. E.g. the equivalent for `document.id('range')` is `$('#range')`. jQuery provides a lot of documentation, so you should be able to figure most of it out by reading it. [Here is a list of available selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Or have a look at [the jQuery tutorial first](http://learn.jquery.com/). Just *linking* to some code and expect others to rewrite it for you is not how SO works.

Comment: Ok, you're right, i just edited my post, thanks!

Comment: @Deptroco, why is this same question asked by different users? I think they are duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899171/mootools-to-jquery-with-canvas-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example with the link, remember that for the easeOutBounce animation you need additional plugin as jQuery alone has just simple animation types. This needs to be done on dom ready or window load functions (in jsfiddle we are using provided checkbox on the left)

```
// SVG stuff
var range = $('#range').get(0);
var bg = $('#counter').get(0);
var ctx = ctx = bg.getContext('2d');
var imd = null;
var circ = Math.PI * 2;
var quart = Math.PI / 2;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = '#99CC33';
ctx.lineCap = 'square';
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 10.0;

imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);

var draw = function(current) {
    ctx.putImageData(imd, 0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(120, 120, 70, -(quart), ((circ) * current) - quart, false);
    ctx.stroke();
}
$(range)
.val(0)
.on('mousemove', function() {
        draw(this.value / 100);
})
.animate({
    'value':100
},{
    'duration':5000,
    'easing':'easeOutBounce',
    'step': function (step, fx) {
        draw(step / 100);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BLtaF/ (with easing plugin attached)

Answer (score 1):

`bg` is a jQuery object now. If you want to access the underlying DOM element, you can use `bg[0]`, e.g. `bg[0].getContext(...)`.

[Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). Then you'll see which error message you are getting and where (e.g. in this case: `TypeError: bg.getContext is not a function`), set breakpoints and inspect variables, and much more!